# Installing JDK 8_251 but keeps saying 7.0_7

Tags: java, java-8, mismatch, drjava

My IDE is DrJava, I am trying to open a previous project but I cant seem to get JDK 8 working.

- I wiped my computer so I've had to reinstall everything.
- But whenever I try to install JDK 8, which is what I coded my program
  in, it keeps saying I have 7.0_7 installed.
- Because of this, I get a "*Current document is out of sync with the
  Interactions Pane and  should be recompiled!*" along with "*target
  release 1.7 conflicts with default source release 1.8*".
- I have installed JDK 6, and it does recognize it, but whenever I try to
  install 8, it sees it as 7.0_7.

I am not sure whether this is an error from DrJava, Java, or i am
   forgetting something. JRE 8 and JDK 8 are installed.

Answer (score 0):

DrJava no longer supports JDK 8 because of some legal stuff with Java. They say they have an alternative, OpenJDK 8, but it was far too complicated to install. I ended up switching over to Eclipse Luna which has JDK 8 built in it.